# Including Id in URI for PUT requests

Tags: rest

I was reading some documents about the appropriate use of URI's using rest services and I came across an example for basic GET .. DELETE requests.

The example uri's were:

Get all users

```
GET http://mydomain.org/api/users
```

Get specific user

```
GET http://mydomain.org/api/users/1
```

Update user

```
PUT http://mydomain.org/api/users/1
```

DELETE user

```
DELETE http://mydomain.org/api/users/1
```

A user resource would be either JSON or XML in the form of:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    FirstName: 'John',
    LastName: 'Doe'
}
```

My question is this. To maintain REST principles, is it required to include the id of the resource within the URI for PUT requests?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.

You want to `PUT` a resource to the same URI you intend to `GET` it from.

[RFC 72314.3.4 PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

Comment: That makes sense. My assumption was that the id would always be provided with the resource, but I guess that won't always be the case.

Comment: And indeed, if you start using URI's in your interface, you might soon find it useful to remove the id from the resource representation itself.

Comment: RFC-2616 is obsoleted by [RFC-7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3)

Comment: @prasanthv what do you mean, did anything change regarding PUT? I don't think so.

Answer (score 17):

I was going to ask a similar question, but I think I found the answer. I am not sure if it is by REST principles, but here is why it would be bad not to include ID in the URI.
So say your `PUT` is like:

```
PUT http://mydomain.org/api/users
```

And then you happen to update multiple users with different id's but the same URI cause there is no ID in your URI. Then, an important thing to know here is that PUT is idempotent http verb. This means that calling it once should have the same effect as calling it mulitple times. Therefore, some intermediate node in the network, just following the fact that you PUT multiple times, might ignore all but one of your requests cause they have the same URI. Finally, that's definetely not what you want cause the intention was to update multiple users not only one.

Comment: I doubt this is possible since the body would be different. Even if you were updating the same resource, you could have different updates (with different values) to it and ignoring some of them is a really unexpected behaviour.

Comment: An idempotent verb should have the same effect regardless of how many times it was invoked. That's mandated by the standard.

Comment: Огњен Шобајић, this can be true only if the request is exactly the same. Lets say we have two requests `PUT: /api/users/1`, with bodies `{"name":"Foo"}` and `{"name":"Bar"}`.

Being idempotent doesn't mean that the second request would be ignored, right? It just means that perfoming the exact same request would have the same effect as performing it only once.

Comment: "Being idempotent verb doesn't mean that second request would be ignored" - yes, that's correct. But it may! It is on the intermediate node in the network to decide if it's going to pass through the second PUT request with the same URI. The HTTP standard allows for ignoring the previous requests with the same URI in some cases (e.g. traffic congestion). I believe that it is URI that matters, not the whole request with body.

Comment: I think this is very nice arctile. It fits in a single screen https://dzone.com/articles/rest-api-path-vs-request-body-parameters

Answer (score 5):

`PUT http://example.com/api/users + body` behaves like the put of a map with the key `http://example.com/api/users` and the value the body. A new entry is created if none exists, else the existing one is overridden.

*Question*: what is the resource behind `http://example.com/api/users` ?

*Answer*: the same than the one provided by `GET http://example.com/api/users`, the **list of all users**.

So, the command `PUT http://example.com/api/users` means that you replace the list of all users with the one you provide.

For consistency, the body should contain an array of users:

```
[
  {
    Id: 1,
    FirstName: 'John',
    LastName: 'Doe'
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    FirstName: 'Albert',
    LastName: 'Einstein'
  }
]
```

Comment: I think this is a good example of API design. It probably isn't something I would allow in a public API as updating that many resources at once could be dangerous, but thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Another benefit for including id in URL for put request is CREATE/UPDATE function can share some logic.

Let's say you have this user table with 3 colums.

```
id(primary key, auto increment) | name | age
```

Creating a user will generate a ID.

```
POST /users
{
  name: "foo"
  age: 25
}
-> generate id 123
```

Because id is in URL, you can use the same request body structure for updating a user.

```
PUT /users/123
{
  name: "bar"
  age: 25
}
```

This might be not so related to REST principal, but it could simplify the code for request handling in practice depending on your languages/frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Great article on this topic can be found here:
https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/

Specifically, recommendations are:

```
GET     /device-management/devices        : Get all devices
POST    /device-management/devices        : Create a new device
GET     /device-management/devices/{id}   : Get the device information identified by "id"
PUT     /device-management/devices/{id}   : Update the device information identified by "id"
DELETE  /device-management/devices/{id}   : Delete device by "id"
```