# RESTful url: PUT or POST for a single record

Tags: api, rest, laravel, restful-url

I understand the difference between PUT (Update) and POST(Create). I am using Laravel.
What I would like to know is what would you use for the example below:

```
domain.com/users/1/reports
```

I am getting all reports for user 1. There will only ever be 1 report per user.
So if user 1 wants to view that report it will be :

```
GET domain.com/users/1/reports
```

Now should I be using PUT or POST to update that report.
PUT requires an ID which I don't see necessary as they will only ever have 1 report eg:

```
PUT domain.com/users/1/report/12
```

So my thinking is to use POST only so the domain name is cleaner

```
POST domain.com/users/1/report
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, the `PUT` request is used for updating existing records, and the `POST` is used for creating new records. `POST` can also be used to update, but it depends how much you want to stick to the conventions.

The http method used doesn't actually have any meaning regarding the exact nature of the resource being requested, it's simply that `GET` is for reads, and `PUT`, `POST`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` are for writes.

If there's only ever one report, there's no need to provide the id in the uri, so `/users/{id}/report` would suffice. You could then just access the report like so:

```
$user = User::with('report')->find($id);
$report = $user->report;
```

This would mean that you'd have to override the default route methods that laravel uses, but as a best practise, you should get in the habit of defining all of your routes rather than relying on laravels defaults.

Answer (score 0):

If there [can be only one report](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) it should be retrieved to as `GET domain.com/users/1/report` and updating that would be the same route `PUT domain.com/users/1/report`.

`PUT` [method does not require an ID of the entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265286/including-id-in-uri-for-put-requests) if there can be only one. I would stick with that as it keeps `PUT` idempotent.

`POST` method is not idempotent, that is, `POST`ing multiple times on the same route with the same arguments produces different results each time, like creates multiple reports for this user.

Idempotence is a good way to achieve understanding of `PUT` and `POST`.

Comment: In Laravel PUT requires an ID http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers. How do I get around it?

Comment: It doesn't mean you may not override it in the `routes.php`. Resource controllers in Laravel is a helper for less writing, not a constant, intact rule-of-thumb systems.

Comment: @user742736 if I understand right, you are not required to have a `{resource}` parameter by default