# why does .net web api use 2 parameters instead of 1 for put methods?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, soa

Why does .NET Web API use 2 parameters instead of 1 for PUT service calls?  So instead of simply passing an Account object, it seems that the standard is to pass accountId and Account as separate parameters. Does Web API work this way to support REST industry standards?  Can anyone here explain the purpose of this particular implementation?  It seems different than traditional SOA where all parameters are encapsulated in request and response objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including Id in URI for PUT requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265286/including-id-in-uri-for-put-requests) I really like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11254510/2901207 (although a bit of opinion is provided).

Answer (score 2):

A PUT is sending a message body (your entity object) to a specific URI for that entity (e.g. /rest/api/itemtype/1234).  When you implement this in WebAPI you have a signature like this:

```
public object Put(int id, object entity){...}
```

So, the first param is the ID taken from the URI, and the second parameter is the message body translated into a strongly typed object.  This is standard usage of PUT within a RESTFul system.